# Let ∼ be an equivalence relation on a set $A$, and let $a, b ∈ A$. Prove that $a ∈ [b]$ iff $b ∈ [a]$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, equivalence-relations

I have the following proof outline, but I am not sure how to get started proving this. Can anyone point me in the right directon?

Proof.
Suppose that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on a set $A$, and that $a,b \in A$. 
[$\Rightarrow$] Suppose $a ∈ [b]$. 
Then $a\sim b$.
Since $\sim$ is symmetric, $b\sim a$.
Therefore $b \in [a]$.
[$\Leftarrow$] On the other hand, suppose $b ∈ [a]$.
Then $b\sim a$.
Since $\sim$ is symmetric, then $a\sim b$.
Therefore $a \in [b]$.

Comment: But... Doesn't it follow immediately from the definition $x\in[y]\iff x\sim y$ ?

Comment: Look at the definition of equivalence class to see exactly what it takes for an element of $A$ to qualify for membership in the class.  Then write down what it means for $a$ to fit this qualification criterion and be in the equivalence class of $b$.  Do the same the other way:  write down exactly what it takes for $b$ to qualify for membership in the equivalence class of $a$.  Then see if you can see why both of the statements you wrote down are equivalent.

Comment: [b] is the set of all elements in A that are related to be related to b. So if a is an element of this set, a is related to b. Since ~ is reflexive, b is related to a. [a] is the set of all elements in in A that are related to a. Since we just found b is related to a reflexively, therefore b ∈ [a]?

Is that correct?

Comment: @dewick49 No not because $\sim$ is "reflexive"; because $\sim$ is **symmetric**. You said it correctly in your proof/question, but not in your comment above. ¶ By the way, all you need to prove is $\Rightarrow$, since obviously $a,b$ are arbitrary and $\Rightarrow$ implies $\Leftarrow$ and thus $\iff$.

Comment: @BrianO Of course, my mistake. That makes perfect sense! Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not as simple as

$$x\in[y]\iff x\sim y\iff y\sim x\iff y\in[x]$$

?

It'd help if we knew *precisely* what definition you are using for $x\in[y]$. There are a lot of equivalent ways to phrase it but you need to use the definition you were provided with for the proof

Comment: The title question being asked is the only information I was given to solve this problem. I have updated my original question with my current proof - is it correct?

Comment: @dewick49 yes that proof is correct.

Comment: and on a side note, is my explanation in the above comments also a correct way of analyzing the problem, or am I misunderstanding the definition of an equivalence class?

Comment: @dewick49 note it's the exact same as my proof except I used a biconditional at every step instead of doing both directions.

Comment: @dewick49 yes that is correct as well. Note again that your explanation is the exact same as your proof, except you're using the phrase "$a$ is related to $b$" in place of the symbol $a\sim b$ every time. No difference.

Comment: The proof is NOT correct because reflexivity is not the right property to use here.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp why is that?

Comment: Well, I thought my comment was clear. Reflexivity means that for each $x$ we have $x\sim x$. But here we have $x$ and $y$, where possibly $x\neq y$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp oh my bad, I didn't even notice he had mixed up the names. Yeah it should be symmetric instead